# Pass State from component to parent

Tags: reactjs

If have a Listing page that contains a table component:

```
class ListingPage extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
    getTableData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,  
  };

componentDidMount() {
         this.props.getTableData(*I want to Pass in sortlist state here*);   

  }

render() {
    return (
      <div> 
 <Table />
     </div>

}
```

And the Table component maintains a `sortlist` state:

```
class Table extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {    
      sortlist: 'someStringData',
    };
render() {
<div>
Table Information etc.
</div>
}
```

The `sortlist` is changed in the table component through various functions. How can I pass that `sortlist` state up to the `ListingPage` component?

Comment: You should use callback prop as is present in above example or you can consider using Redux. And from button Component, you can dispatch action which changes Redux state and pass new props to the parent component. But in this case, you will have your data in props, not in compoennt state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a function along to `Table` from `ListingPage` that gets called whenever the `sortlist` is changed.

*ListingPage component:*

```js
class ListingPage extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getTableData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onSortChange(s) {
    console.log(s);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table onSortChange={s => this.onSortChange(s)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Table component:*

```js
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortlist: 'someStringData',
    };
  }

  somethingThatTriggersSortListToChange(s) {
    this.props.onSortChange(s);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Table Information etc.</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering above answer, You can also use redux store in this case when you want to pass state from child to parent. Make an action call and store the state in redux store and get the state in parent component. This is another way of playing from child to parent component.

```
this.props.saveToStore(this.state.sortlist);
```

In your action file

```
cost SAVE_TO_STORE = “SAVE_TO_STORE”;

export function saveToStore(sortlist){
     return {
          type: SAVE_TO_STORE,
          sortlist
      }
   }
```

Like store state in reducer and get the state in your parent component and return as props i.e., in mapStateToProps(state, props) function using redux connect method.